# Getting values out of foreach array

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

I'm wanting to get the values out of an arrray so I can set them later on inside some javascript.

```
$meta_queries = array(
            'type_of_load' => 'type_of_load',
            'number_of_pallets' => 'number_of_pallets',
            'type_of_trailer_required' => 'trailor',
            'euro_pallets' => 'euro_pallet'
        );

        foreach($meta_queries as $key => $value) {

            if (isset($_GET[$value]) && $_GET[$value] !== '') {

                array_push($v_args['meta_query'], array(
                    'key' => $key,
                    'value' => $_GET[$value],
                    'compare' => '='
                ));

            }

    <script>
        // set values from array
        jQuery('div1').val("VALUE1");
        jQuery('div2').val("VALUE2");

    </script>
```

Within the loop, I want to be able to get the value out of the array and then add it to the javascript.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Could you could simply convert the array to json format and echo that as a js variable? 
ie: var json=<?php echo json_encode( $meta_queries );?>;

Comment: @uchiha - no, it shouldn't need quotes as it will be a JSON object rather than a string

Comment: what should I do then? I am still confused with this :)

Comment: Where is the confusion - you build an array manually in php, then you are generating / populating another array ($v_args) based upon the array you created before but using a $_GET value too along with the keys. What is the purpose of this? Understanding what you are trying to do will help decide what you should do and thus guide you in your programming.
I do not understand what the javascript lines at the end are supposed to do as the code (php) doesn't really reflect the values (VALUE1/2).

Comment: The values will be from a get value which are taken from the query string.